# PHP Web Server build with php. Can I get it to support SSL?

Tags: php, ssl

I know that php has a build in web server but, me being the person I am I started to write one with php itself. So far it works and I plan on publishing it on GitHub once it is more robust. But first, I thought I would query the minds on this page to see if I can add SSL support to the server. I was thinking that I could use PHP and some form of RSA to read the ssl certificates and use them to publish an SSL enabled php web server. Im not to sure though on the construction of SSL ad a whole. I was going to start looking at the source code to see if I could emulate something similar with php.

My question is this, has anyone emulated SSL encryption with php or does anyone have an Idea of something I can look at for reference?

I know this idea is lame and why would I spend the time but, it is just out of my own curiosity. Please only provide constructive responses as I know my plan is rediculus and pointless it is more just a learning test for me.

Thank You,
-This guy

Comment: “I started to write one myself”. Is this in PHP or C? If PHP, yes, PHP can handle TLS using OpenSSL, and should be able to handle both sides of the cert. I use Symfony’s CLI for serving, even for WordPress, because it helps with TLS automatically. Unfortunately it is closed sourced

Comment: It is 100% php. Currently starts/runs/works and has a routing API.  I did not know symphony had a TLS server. Interesting.

Comment: So, not try to dissuade you or anything, but is this just for debugging/developing purposes? And, your server is basically invoked by `php script.php`, is that right? The CLI binary can’t handle multiple events at the same time (AFAIK) so you will run into bottlenecks under just minor demands including static assets, I’d think